# sasl2 by macport lack of login/plain authentication mechanisms

Tags: svn, authentication, macports, sasl

I'm trying to use svn protocol to connect to our company's svn. It uses "LOGIN PLAIN" as authentication mechanism. I use macport to install subversion 1.8.3. However, it doesn't supports these two authentication mechanism. It reports "svn: E210007: Cannot negotiate authentication mechanism".

I took me almost a day and finally I found out it maybe the issue of sasl2 module. But I don't know how to fix it. Could anyone help me?
   Thanks a lot

Here're my debugging information

```
 $/opt/local/bin/svn --version
 ....
 * ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol. - with Cyrus SASL authentication
 ...
 #/opt/local/sbin/saslauthd -v
 saslauthd 2.1.25
 authentication mechanisms: getpwent kerberos5 pam rimap
```

Looks like login/plain is not supported. After I try to add LOGIN or PLAIN, it'll return error too.

```
 #/opt/local/sbin/saslauthd  -a login
 saslauthd[50249] :set_auth_mech   : unknown authentication mechanism: login
```

But actually the mechanism is in ports/security/cyrus-sasl2/Portfile.

```
 configure.args          --mandir=${prefix}/share/man \
                    --with-openssl=${prefix} \
                    --with-dbpath=${prefix}/etc/sasldb2 \
                    --with-plugindir=${prefix}/lib/sasl2 \
                    --with-saslauthd=${prefix}/var/state/saslauthd \
                    --with-pwcheck=${prefix}/var/pwcheck \
                    --disable-macos-framework \
                    --enable-srp \
                    --enable-srp-setpass \
                    --enable-login \
                    --enable-ntlm \
                    --with-rc4=openssl
```

And also plain/login library were both built into /opt/local/lib

```
  $ls /opt/local/lib/sasl2/libplain.*
   /opt/local/lib/sasl2/libplain.2.0.25.so /opt/local/lib/sasl2/libplain.2.so      /opt/local/lib/sasl2/libplain.so
  $ls /opt/local/lib/sasl2/liblogin.*
    /opt/local/lib/sasl2/liblogin.2.0.25.so /opt/local/lib/sasl2/liblogin.2.so      /opt/local/lib/sasl2/liblogin.so
```

Comment: Are you on OS X Mavericks?

Comment: yes, it runs on OSX 10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problems. Maybe its related to this: http://trac.macports.org/ticket/40885

I am on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: I set libsasl2.2.0.25.dylib  links to /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.0.21.dylib under /opt/local/lib to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you tell me where you got the libsasl2.2.0.21.dylib from? Did you install it with mac ports? If so, could you tell me how?

This is what I see: `libsasl2.2.0.25.dylib`, `libsasl2.2.dylib -> libsasl2.2.0.25.dylib`, `libsasl2.dylib -> libsasl2.2.0.25.dylib` and a dir `sasl2`